# Rotating Images using GDI+

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, gdi+, metadata, jpeg

I am working on image rotation using GDI+. As per image metadata, there should be 8 different types of orientation (http://www.impulseadventure.com/photo/exif-orientation.html). But I am getting the same orientation for all the images whether they are in Horizontal or Vertical orientation. Can anyone suggest where is the problem or am I missing something ?

Thanks!

Comment: FYI GDI+ and ASP.NET [don't necessarily play well](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.aspx): `Classes within the System.Drawing namespace are not supported for use within a Windows or ASP.NET service. Attempting to use these classes from within one of these application types may produce unexpected problems, such as diminished service performance and run-time exceptions. For a supported alternative, see Windows Imaging Components.`

Comment: Windows Imaging Components are not supported either, the documentation is incorrect.  I'm also 100% sure that System.Drawing is not supported because it's extremely difficult to use properly, and if not used properly, it will cause memory and handle leaks. But it is possible to use it properly, and safely.

Comment: [Clarification] Windows Imaging Components are only supported on Release 2 of Windows Server 2008 and higher, and also on Windows 7. Earlier versions suffer from the same problems as GDI+. WPF is not supported, period. They're still discovering new memory leaks with it. Both GDI+ and WIC (on those 2 platforms) can be used safely in a web service, if you follow all the rules and know all the bugs. [The imageresizing.net](http://imageresizing.net) library allows you to use either one.

Answer (score 1):

A couple days ago I added automatic rotation to [the imageresizing.net library](http://imageresizing.net) as the AutoRotate plugin. I'm including the relevant source code, which should hopefully help you.

```
if (!"true".Equals(settings["autorotate"], StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) return RequestedAction.None;

int propertyId = 0x0112;
PropertyItem pi;
try {
    pi = b.GetPropertyItem(propertyId);
} catch (ArgumentException) {
    return RequestedAction.None;
}
if (pi == null) return RequestedAction.None;

int total = 0;

foreach (byte by in pi.Value) total += by; //Does not handle values larger than 255, but it doesn't need to, and is endian-agnostic.

if (total == 8) b.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipNone);
if (total == 3) b.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipNone);
if (total == 6) b.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);

if (total == 2) b.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipX);
if (total == 4) b.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipX);
if (total == 5) b.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipY);
if (total == 7) b.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipY);

b.RemovePropertyItem(propertyId);
```

As an FYI, if you *are* doing image resizing in ASP.NET, [you should read this article](http://nathanaeljones.com/163/20-image-resizing-pitfalls/) on how to do it safely, or use the [ImageResizing.Net library](http://imageresizing.net) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Just a small improvement,

I would not test for an argumentexception, that costs CPU cycles.

```
   var orientation_index = Array.IndexOf(b.PropertyIdList, propertyId );

        if ( orientation_index <0) return RequestedAction.None;
        byte total =0;
        foreach (byte b in b.GetPropertyItem(OrientationId).Value)
        {
            total += b;
        }
```