# Does a PropertyItem always use Intel byte-order?

Tags: .net, bitmap, jpeg, exif

In a Windows Bitmap, the PropertyItems collection has a set of PropertyItems with values returned as bytes. These can include 2-byte and 4-bytes integers. The format can be Intel or non-Intel byte order (big or little Endian), according to the Exif specification for JPG and TIFF.

Is there a Bitmap or other property that tells which byte-order is being used in the PropertyItem values? If not, does .net automatically convert PropertyItem values to Intel byte-order if necessary?

Comment: You must be using some unnamed tool. Windows Bitmap format does not have such a structure itself.

Comment: System.Drawing.Imaging.PropertyItem, accessed on a bitmap with Image.GetPropertyItem, Image.SetPropertyItem Methods.

Comment: A very good question. According to the reference source, the .net PropertyItem code is just [a wrapper around the corresponding GDI+ methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdiplus/-gdiplus-reading-and-writing-metadata-use). For small numbers (< 256, for example, the "Orientation" values), a [nice workaround I've seen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7875730/87698) is to just add all bytes.